# Using Comonad Fix Combinators

Tags: haskell, comonad, fixpoint-combinators

So I've been experimenting with fixed points lately and have finally struggled
through regular fixed points enough to discover some uses; now I'm moving onto
comonadic fixed points and I'm afraid I've gotten stuck;

Here's a few examples of what I've tried and what has/hasn't worked:

```
{-# language DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# language FlexibleInstances #-}
module WFix where

import Control.Comonad
import Control.Comonad.Cofree
import Control.Monad.Fix
```

So I started with loeb's theorem as a list; each element of the list is a function
which takes the end result to compute its answer; this lets me do 'spreadsheet'
calculations where values can depend on other values.

```
spreadSheetFix :: [Int]
spreadSheetFix = fix $ \result -> [length result, (result !! 0) * 10, (result !! 1) + 1, sum (take 3 result)]
```

Okay, so I have basic fix working, time to move on to the comonad types!
Here's a few simple comonads to use for examples:

```
  data Stream a = S a (Stream a)
    deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)

  next :: Stream a -> Stream a
  next (S _ s) = s

  instance Comonad Stream where
    extract (S a _) = a
    duplicate s@(S _ r) = S s (duplicate r)

  instance ComonadApply Stream where
    (S f fs) <@> (S a as) = S (f a) (fs <@> as)

  data Tape a = Tape [a] a [a]
    deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)

  moveLeft, moveRight :: Tape a -> Tape a
  moveLeft w@(Tape [] _ _) = w
  moveLeft (Tape (l:ls) a rs) = Tape ls l (a:rs)

  moveRight w@(Tape _ _ []) = w
  moveRight (Tape ls a (r:rs)) = Tape (a:ls) r rs

  instance Comonad Tape where
    extract (Tape _ a _) = a
    duplicate w@(Tape l _ r) = Tape lefts w rights
      where
        lefts = zipWith const (tail $ iterate moveLeft w) l
        rights = zipWith const (tail $ iterate moveRight w) r

  instance ComonadApply Tape where
    Tape l f r <@> Tape l' a r' = Tape (zipWith ($) l l') (f a) (zipWith ($) r r')
```

Okay so the following combinators come from [Control.Comonad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.1/docs/Control-Comonad.html);

```
wfix :: Comonad w => w (w a -> a) -> a
wfix w = extract w (extend wfix w)

cfix :: Comonad w => (w a -> a) -> w a
cfix f = fix (extend f)

kfix :: ComonadApply w => w (w a -> a) -> w a
kfix w = fix $ \u -> w <@> duplicate u
```

I started with trying out wfix:

```
streamWFix :: Int
streamWFix = wfix st
  where
    incNext = succ . extract . next
    st = (S incNext (S incNext (S (const 0) st)))

> streamWFix
-- 2
```

This one seems to work by calling the first `w a -> a` on w until reaching
a resolution `const 0` in this case; that makes sense. We can also do this
with a Tape:

```
selfReferentialWFix :: Int
selfReferentialWFix = wfix $ Tape [const 10] ((+5) . extract . moveLeft) []
-- selfReferentialWFix == 15
```

K, I think I get that one, but the next ones I'm kind of stuck,
I don't seem to have an intuition for what cfix is supposed to do.
Even the simplest possible thing I could think of spins forever 
when I evaluate it; even trying to extract the first element of the stream
using getOne fails.

```
getOne :: Stream a -> a
getOne (S a _) = a

simpleCFix :: Stream Int
simpleCFix = cfix go
  where
    go _ = 0
```

Similarly with kfix; even simple tries don't seem to terminate.
My understanding of kfix was that the function in each 'slot' gets
passed a copy of the evaluated comonad focused on that spot; is that the case?

I tried using 'getOne' on this:

```
streamKFix :: Stream Int
streamKFix = kfix st
  where
    go _ = 0
    st = S go st
```

Here's a finite attempt using Tape which also fails to run:

```
tapeKFix :: Tape Int
tapeKFix = kfix $ Tape [] (const 0) []
```

So; down to my question, could someone please offer some runnable (non-trivial)
examples of using cfix and kfix, and explain how they work? I plan to use kfix to eventually do a "Conway's
game of life" style experiment, am I correct in thinking that kfix would be useful
in working with neighbourhoods around a given cell?

Feel free to ask
any clarifying questions and help me expand my knowledge and intuition of fix!

Thanks!

Comment: I just watched the [referenced video for `kfix`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7F-BzOB670) from the  [`Control.Comonad` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.1/docs/Control-Comonad.html). Thanks for introducing me to this.

Comment: That video is what spawned my curiosity! I have yet to try his spreadsheet lib,  but that'll be next!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ComonadApply` and `Comonad` instances for `Tape` are insufficiently lazy to be used with `kfix`.

`duplicate` for `Tape` requires that you prove the tape exists before it can conclude that the result is a `Tape`

```
instance Comonad Tape where
  extract (Tape _ a _) = a
  duplicate w@(Tape l _ r) = Tape lefts w rights
--             ^             ^
-- matches a Tape            |               
-- before determining that the result is a Tape
```

`<@>` checks that both arguments are tapes before it can conclude that the result is a `Tape`

```
instance ComonadApply Tape where
  Tape l f r <@> Tape l' a r' = Tape (zipWith ($) l l') (f a) (zipWith ($) r r')
-- ^             ^              ^
-- matches two Tapes            |
-- before detrmining that the result is a Tape
```

Combined there's no way for `kfix (Tape _ _ _)` to ever produce `Tape`

```
kfix w            = fix $ \u -> w            <@> duplicate u
kfix (Tape _ _ _) = fix $ \u -> (Tape _ _ _) <@> duplicate u
kfix (Tape _ _ _) = fix $ \u -> (Tape _ _ _) <@> case u of (Tape _ _ _) -> ...
--                         ^                                |
--                         ----------- <<loop>> -------------
```

You can fix this by making `duplicate`, `<@>`, or both more productive by using [irrefutable patterns](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html). A pattern `~(Tape l a r)` matches even if the `Tape` constructor hasn't been produced yet. Here's how you'd use it to make `duplicate` productive

```
instance Comonad Tape where
  extract (Tape _ a _) = a
  duplicate w@(~(Tape l _ r)) = Tape lefts w rights
    where
      lefts = zipWith const (tail $ iterate moveLeft w) l
      rights = zipWith const (tail $ iterate moveRight w) r
```

Irrefutable pattern matches are equivalent to using functions to extract values. For `duplicate` it's equivalent to writing

```
left  (Tape l _ _) = l
right (Tape _ _ r) = r

instance Comonad Tape where
  extract (Tape _ a _) = a
  duplicate w = Tape lefts w rights
    where
      l = left w
      r = right w
      ...
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks for the link to that article, very useful! I applied your changes to duplicate and I can now do some simple kfix attempts now; I'm still a little confused about some things though; for instance I'm not getting my expected output for this example: https://gist.github.com/ChrisPenner/a8e7a72f4765aaa9941a58b70fd57ec3

Comment: I don't think `moveLeft` and `moveRight` are lazy enough (or can be lazy enough) for `Tape [a] a [a]`. `moveLeft` has to look inside the left side before deciding what it's doing to compute the left, middle, or right values. My intuition says that any reference that needs to inspect the structure to decide the structure isn't going to work if it's used as part of `duplicate` or `<@>`. A [`Tape (Stream a) a (Stream a)` works](https://gist.github.com/Cedev/c9f3769eb7bab6eea6c323925cae8215).

Comment: That's makes sense, as for the example I posted, it doesn't use moveLeft or moveRight, and every execution depends only on what's to the left, so I'd figure the leftmost cell should execute and flow through to the others?

Comment: Full disclosure, the end goal is to use kfix to compute a 2D Vector using results of computing the neighbours of each cell. In theory each cell has exactly one neighbour as a dependency, so the computation should terminate. Hopefully Vectors are lazy enough? I'm making vector a comonad by pairing it with an index, and I restrict all vectors to be the same dimensions

Comment: Maybe I'll end up using this lib: https://github.com/kwf/ComonadSheet/blob/master/README.md but I'd like to give it a try on my own first!

Comment: Looks like that lib is completely BitRot at this point, guess I'm on my own.